# GAE Managed VM with automatic scaling and resources config fails with HttpError 409

Tags: java, google-app-engine, managed-vm

I'm experiencing the following error intermittently while deploying a java application to appengine using managed VMs with explicit resource configuration:

> Deployment failed: https://www.googleapis.com/autoscaler/v1beta2/projects/managedvm409example/zones/us-central1-f/autoscalers?alt=json returned "Autoscaler resource with this name already exists in this zone or there exists an Autoscaler controlling the given target."> Deployed Version: 1.385892435190233331

Here's the configuration I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>managedvm409example</application>
    <version>1</version>

    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>

    <vm>true</vm>

    <automatic-scaling>
        <min-num-instances>2</min-num-instances>
        <max-num-instances>10</max-num-instances>
        <cool-down-period-sec>90</cool-down-period-sec>
    </automatic-scaling>

    <resources>
        <cpu>1</cpu>
        <memory-gb>4</memory-gb>
        <disk-size-gb>10</disk-size-gb>
    </resources>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The problem seems to go away if the *automatic-scaling* configuration element is removed, but there doesn't seem to be anything exotic in there. Anyone have any ideas on what might be going on?

**EDIT:** The situation doesn't really change with *automatic-scaling* removed, apparently, it's just intermittent.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to the problem? im currently experiencing the same, removed the auto scaling and still the same :(

Comment: @monmonja Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to this issue yet.

Comment: Even if you experience an intermittent issue, it's beneficial if you can open a [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) thread which provides as much information as possible, including the affected app id, the timeframe, and any relevant config files, as you supplied here. You might want to include other relevant information, within discretion, such as whether you're running an [Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/). This way the root cause of the issue has a hope of being discovered and fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I wasn't aware there was an exposed issue tracker for GAE. Will report issue if it isn't already.