# google managedvm delete instance foverver

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, managed-vm

I recently changed the version of the app when deployment and everytime i execute gcloud compute instances list it will list out the old version, i tried manually deleting from the console and it works but after few minutes it will go back. I tried gcloud delete too
gcloud compute instances delete instance --delete-disks all

Stopping doesnt help to, as it is a running instance would it charge me on its up time? How do i completely remove it (Did tried removing appengine version too but it keeps coming back)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having a lot of trouble with deploying (with versions) and deleting instances on Google Compute Engine's managed VMs. **Here's a solution I found for deleting the default GCE managed VM:**

- Make sure you have the up-to-date GCE components. Run `gcloud components update` in the Google Cloud SDK Shell.
- In your app.yaml, remove the `vm:true`, `resources:` section, and `manual scaling:` section.
- Navigate to Compute -> App Engine -> Versions and record the `<default-version-number>`. Mine looks like `20150722t1245032` with the words `(default)` indicating the default version.
- Deploy the application, set the default, and specify the default version. `gcloud preview app deploy "...\app.yaml" --set-default --version=<default-version-number>`.
- Navigate to Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances. Select the default instance and delete.

I was also taught **how to stop deploying additional instances**:

- The key is to specify the version number `gcloud preview app deploy "...\app.yaml" --set-default --version=<version-number>`. @ZacharyNewman was able to help me with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484826/how-to-stop-creating-extra-instances-when-using-google-managed-vms).

And finally, this is **how to delete the additional versions of an instance**:

- Navigate to Compute -> App Engine -> Versions and delete the versions you don't want.
- Navigate to Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances. Select the instances you don't want and delete.

Hope this helps!

Comment: btw have you experience this one while deploying multiple times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564262/gae-managed-vm-with-automatic-scaling-and-resources-config-fails-with-httperror